# Is Direct3D feasible for zoom and pan of large images?

Tags: directx, direct3d

I want to make an image viewer for large images (up to 2000 x 8000 pixels) with very responsive zooming and panning, say 30 FPS or more. One option I came up with is to create a 3D scene with the image as a sort of fixed billboard, then move the camera forward/back to zoom and up/down/left/right to pan.

That basic idea seems reasonable to me, but I don't have experience with 3D graphics. Is there some fundamental thing I'm missing that will make my idea difficult or impossible? What might cause problems or be challenging to implement well? What part of this design will limit the maximum image size? Any guesses as to what framerate I might achieve?

I also welcome any guidance or suggestions on how to approach this task for someone brand new to Direct3D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems pretty doable to me, 30 fps even seems quite low, you can certainly achieve a solid 60 (minimum)

One image at 8k*2k resolution is about 100 megs of VRAM (with mipmaps), so with today's graphics cards it's not much of an issue, you'll of course face challenges if you need to load several at the same time.

DirectX 11 supports 16k*16k size textures, so for maximum size you should be sorted.

If you want to just show your image flat your should not even need any 3d transformations, 2d scaling/translations will do just fine.